# jsforce query similar to mongo's $in?

Tags: jsforce

I can do simple find and findOnes where I have, for example, one ID:

```
const conn = new jsforce.Connection({
// you can change loginUrl to connect to sandbox or prerelease env.
 loginUrl : 'https://test.salesforce.com'
});

conn.login(USER_NAME, PASSWORD);

let idToFind = '1fasd23fsadfa3333';

conn.sobject('Deals').findOne({Id: idToFind}).execute(callback);
```

What I have is an array of Deal IDs... how can I grab all the deals in the array? Coming from mongo I'd like to do something like this using an [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

```
let dealsToRetrieve = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];

let query = {Id: {$in: dealsToRetrieve} };

conn.sobject('Deals')
.find(query)
.execute(callback);
```

I'd like to use the more mongo/chainable queries if possible, but if not, how is this done with salesforce's more SQL query language?

Comment: Did you check documentation already? there is retrieve method that allows you to get records by multiple ids (https://jsforce.github.io/document/#crud). If you want to use find -- there is an $in operator, that take as parameter array, so .find( { Id : { $in : ['id1','id2'] } }) should work as expected

Comment: @kurunve, I just realized picklists are stored as strings separated by ';' and not as arrays. Will using $in still work?

Comment: Well, that would much easier to check for you rather than asking here. In any case, you can easily do splin on ';' and get an array :)